# Cannot change value of data after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Sorry for a somewhat duplicate post. But the previous post was to confusing.

In a nutshell, I have a span element with an id of `maxfiles_id`.

When you select a value form a drop list, it changes the value on the page for `maxfiles_id` that works.

However, I have an input field with an `id` of `file_limit` and a `data-count='some value'`.

When the AJAX does its magic, it changes the `maxfiles_id` on the screen but does not affect the `data-count` value.

Here is the code which I broke into two sections to simplify it.

```
function setUploads(val) {
  if (val == 0) {
    val = 10;
  }
  $("#maxfiles_id").html(val);
  $("#file_limit").data('count', val);
}
```

And here is the code for when the drop list selection is made.  BTW, the `SELECT` id is `upload_category`.

```
$("#upload_category").on("change", function() {
  var catid = $("#upload_category").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxqueries.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      catlimit: catid
    },
    success: function(data) {
      setUploads(data);
    }
  });
})
```

Why on earth can I not change the value for `data-count`?

Here is where I want the change to take place:

```
<input type='file' name='file[]' data-maxfilesize='$maxfilesize' accept='image/*' id='file_limit' data-count='$maxfiles' multiple>
```

I am trying to set a new value for `maxfiles` based on drop list.

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: `.attr('data-count' , val)` instead of `.data('count' , val)`

Comment: tried .attr('data-count' , val) still no go.

Comment: What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: Here is what I have loaded 3.1.1